# Azure SQL DWH delete and restore it when requires

Tags: azure-synapse

Is there an option to restore the deleted database in SQL DWH at a later time(more than a year )?

Comment: I'm planning to delete a database on SQL DWH. But if requires I need to restore the database.  Need to get confirmation about this.

Comment: I suggest you read the produce documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/backup-and-restore

Comment: Thanks, @Nick.McDermaid for responding. The problem is I came across another document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-restore-database-portal) where there is an option to restore the deleted database. But in the document which you mentioned, it is different. I've asked this question to get confirmation from a person who restored the deleted database in SQLDWH.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation [clearly indicates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-sql-data-warehouse-provides-a-frictionless-development-using-sql-server-data-tools/) that when an Azure SQL Data Warehouse is dropped it keeps the final snapshot for seven days:

> When you drop a data warehouse, SQL Data Warehouse creates a final
>   snapshot and saves it for seven days. You can restore the data
>   warehouse to the final restore point created at deletion.

The same article also mentions the fact you can vote for this feature here:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/35114410-user-defined-retention-periods-for-restore-points

Even if you could do this, you are basically leaving it up to someone else to be in charge of your warehouse backups.  What you could do instead is take control:

1. Store your Azure SQL Data Warehouse schema in source code control (eg git, Azure DevOps formerly VSTS, etc).  If it isn't there already you can reverse engineer the schema using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) versions 17.x onwards or even use the [SSDT preview feature](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-sql-data-warehouse-provides-a-frictionless-development-using-sql-server-data-tools/)
2. Export your data to Data Lake or Azure Blob Storage using `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT (CETAS)`.  This will export your data as flat files to storage where it won't be deleted.   Alternately use Azure Data Factory to export the data and zip it up to save space.
3. When you need to recreate the warehouse, simply redeploy the schema from source code control and redeploy the data, eg via CTAS in to staging tables, or use Azure Data Factory to re-import.  If you saved your external tables in the schema you save to source code control then it will just be there when you redeploy.  `INSERT` back in to the main tables from the external tables.

In this way you are in charge of your warehouse schema and your data to be recreated at any point you require, whether it be a day, a month or years.

A simple diagram of the proposed design:
[image: adw support diagram]

Comment: Any constructive feedback @JRJ?